# Highcharts React with Typescript Event Typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

### Highcharts Event with TypeScript

I am using custom events in my Highcharts together with the React wrapper.
As an example it toggles the legend when opening and closing the full screen.

```
const options: Highcharts.Options = {
  chart: {
    events: {
      fullscreenOpen: function (this: any) {
        this.update({
          legend: {
            enabled: true,
          },
        });
      },
      fullscreenClose: function (this: any) {
        this.update({
          legend: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        });
      },
    },
  },
};
```

### Correct typing?

How can I type the event correctly and can get rid of the `this: any`?

### Code & Demo

[Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-p1ghql?file=App.tsx)

[Stackblitz Demo](https://react-starter-typescript-p1ghql.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: I would suggest you look at the documentation of Highcharts. https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.FullScreenfullscreenCloseCallbackFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check types in Highcharts API. In your case it will be:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      fullscreenOpen: function (this: Highcharts.Chart) {
        this.update({
          legend: {
            enabled: true
          }
        });
      },
      fullscreenClose: function (this: Highcharts.Chart) {
        this.update({
          legend: {
            enabled: false
          }
        });
      },
    },
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-nv7acw?file=App.tsx

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.fullscreenOpen

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.FullScreenfullscreenOpenCallbackFunction